# Where can I find Hisser DNA Level IV?

Tags: firefall

I was searching for Hissers all Day but did not find any.

In what Areas can I find enough Hissers (spawns while thumping or in vicinity ) to farm for a Hisser DNA Level IV which I need to build a Turret II? Please provide Screenshots of the map if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to craft a blue crystite hybrid module, you don't need dna level 4. Even though that's what the recipe links to, you can also use varying amount of lesser materials to craft the same thing. 50 standard dna samples can be used in place of 1 level 4. The recipe is under crystite hybrid modules. You can usually find a good number of hisser pods in the rockpools, at around (922,687)

Comment: You can also find a *lot* of hisser nests in Diamondhead, Copacabana's melding bubble.